# Wordpress keeps logging deprecated notices even though i've disabled it

Tags: php, wordpress

Does wordpress just like to completely ignore php settings? In php.ini i have disabled error logging for deprecated notices yet debug.log keeps filling up with them:

[01-Feb-2022 11:07:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is **deprecated** since version 2.2.0! The `siteurl` option is deprecated for the family of `bloginfo()` functions. Use the `url` option instead. in /home/utterly/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5495

In php.ini i have:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I also have this in wp-config.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Yet it's still filling up the debug.log file?

Comment: The debug.log is not the php error log.

Comment: i didn't say it was the php error log, but wordpress stores the errors there

Comment: Only if you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it in wp-config.php

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Comment: i have all that, we have it logging errors in debug.log, i don't want to totally disable error reporting only the deprecated notices

Comment: define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); made the trick

Comment: debug_display would disable all logging. I've fixed this by reverting to php 7.4.26 while I'm working on localhost in order to see what is going on in logs without Wordpress clogging the file.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 6.2.2, while getting rid of deprecations in my plugin code, I have learned that this combination of `wp-config.php` lines works nicely.

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

It puts the deprecation notices into `wp-content/debug.log` but not into the html output. This means I can grep for my own deprecation notices without getting the html page output disrupted by other plugins' hundreds of notices.  (I'm looking at you, WooCommerce, in late June 2023.)